# Gaslighting ; criminal or civil

Tags: criminal-law, criminal-procedure, mental-health, stalking

Gaslighting can be extremely damaging. Like Gang-Stalking, it is near impossible to prove it executed correctly.
How can gaslighting be prosecuted as a crime?

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=psychological+abuse

Comment: @BlueDogRanch also (in some circumstances) possibly https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=fraud

Comment: Your title doesn't match your final sentence.

Answer (score 4):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

There isn't a law that defines '[gaslighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting)' as an offence.

*Generally* it isn't unlawful to mislead, deceive or lie - of course, there are exceptions such as [fraud](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/35/contents), [misleading advertising](https://www.gov.uk/marketing-advertising-law/regulations-that-affect-advertising), [perjury](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Geo5/1-2/6) and so on.

So the answer to your question must depend on what is meant by 'gaslighting' and the circumstances in which it has been said to have occurred. It seems to me that people understand and use the word differently - for me it pertains to intimate or family relationships (as in its alleged origin, the film *Gaslight*), some people seem to use it for different serious behaviour and other people use it for relatively trivial behaviour.

In the intimate or family relationship context, gaslighting might be part or all of the behaviour alleged to be the controlling or coercive behaviour contrary to [s76 Serious Crime Act 2015](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/9/section/76):

> 76 Controlling or coercive behaviour in an intimate or family
> relationship
>
> (1)A person (A) commits an offence if—
>
> (a)A repeatedly or continuously engages in behaviour towards another
> person (B) that is controlling or coercive,
>
> (b)at the time of the behaviour, A and B are personally connected,
>
> (c)the behaviour has a serious effect on B, and
>
> (d)A knows or ought to know that the behaviour will have a serious
> effect on B.

[Here is the Crown Prosecution Service guidance for prosecuting s76 Serious Crime Act 2015](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/controlling-or-coercive-behaviour-intimate-or-family-relationship).

Simply lying about one's job or income to have a one-night stand would not constitute the s76 offence.

Behaviour that causes psychological injury that amounts to recognisable psychiatric illness could be assault occasioning Actual Bodily Harm (ABH) contrary to s47 Offences Against the Person Act 1861 ([see CPS Guidance for ABH](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/offences-against-person-incorporating-charging-standard)).